# how to stop Visual Studio 2010 outlining of Jscript

Tags: visual-studio-2010, jscript, outlining

I'm editing JavaScript using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.

But every time I open a a .htm .html or .js file, it defaults to adding all the annoying little outlining + symbols.

In VS C++ and other languages, you can turn this off by setting Tools > Options >  > Formatting

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed?  I don't believe VS supports outlining in JS by default.

Comment: Once you figure out how to disable it, let me know how to *enable* it.  Sounds like a great feature.

Comment: Not only does it SUPPORT outlining, it defaults to it, and there's no way to turn it off.  I never got into outlinining in source code -- I got a 27" vertical monitor and a 27" horizontal one, so I'm a big time code slider.   :-)   This sure beats punch cards and print outs all over the dining room table back in the "dark ages."